# Manupulate td using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following html structure.

```
<td class="coll-1">
   <b><a href="#">Some link text</a></b>
   <p>Description lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect</p>
</td>
```

And I want to make something like this using jQuery. I can not modify the code so have to use this.

```
<td class="coll-1">
   <div class="col-1-data">
     <b><a href="#">Some link text</a></b>
     <p>Description lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect</p>
   </div>
</td>
```

Please do needful

Comment: You may use `innerHtml` to change content within your `<td></td>` tags.

Comment: Why don't you just change the class of the TD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do the following using the [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) function.

```
$(".coll-1").wrapInner("<div class='col-1-data' />");
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
$("td.coll-1 *").wrapAll('<div class="col-1-data" />');
```

**edit:** due to some comments, it works: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felixsigl/dWwGc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would've went with felixsigl's answer above, but seeing that your `<TD>`'s are numbered, I'm assuming that these are actually numbered and repeated on your page. If that is the case, we'll have to build on his answer a bit more.

The following code:

1. wraps a `<TD>`'s children with a `<DIV>` element as specified, and
2. assigns a numbered class for the `<DIV>` corresponding to the parent `<TD>`'s class. (i.e. coll-2 => col-2-data)

**Code:**

```
    $('td[class^="coll-"]').each(function() {

        var el = $(this);
        var num = el.attr('class').split('-')[1];

        el.children().wrapAll('<div class="col-'+num+'-data" />');

    });
```

I'll see what I can do with simplifying it, but this currently works fine. [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYUu9/1/)